# How many ballots have been sequestered in Pennsylvania and Michigan?

Tags: united-states, election, ballot

By court orders, Pennsylvania and Michigan have been commanded to sequester domestic ballots that arrived at counting stations after the traditional deadlines.
For the purposes of this question, it is unnecessary to detail the legal arguments that lead to the orders.

Rather, this question is confined to two facts (that should be knowable at this time):

1. How many ballots have been sequestered in each state ? and
2. Have those ballots been opened and the votes counted but the results are also segregated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pennsylvania - About 5000

From [this article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/pennsylvania-ballots-gop/2020/11/06/064fdf94-2056-11eb-90dd-abd0f7086a91_story.html)

> In all, the U.S. Postal Service processed roughly 4,900 ballots in Pennsylvania on Wednesday and Thursday, according to agency data. In his order Friday, Alito said that all ballots received by mail after 8 p.m. Tuesday must be kept in a secure and sealed container separate from other voted ballots, and must be counted separately, if counties were including them in their tallies.

These ballots have almost certainly been counted

> However, Alito did not direct election officials to stop counting the ballots, as the Republicans had also sought.

I can't find any sequestered ballots in Michigan.

Comment: Good Find ! I assume that the domestic PA sequestered ballots are captured between 8 PM on 11/3/202 and ending at 5PM on 11/6/2020). Do we have any idea if the voters choices/results on those sequestered ballots are also sequestered? . (Or have they been included in the total count - subject to possible count reduction)

Comment: I would assume they are in the final totals, but counted in such as way as to remove them if SCOTUS intervenes